# Unexplained errors using a loopback device as a PV for LVM

Tags: linux, initramfs

I am trying to take a Azure cloud Ubuntu 14.04 image (with a single partition for /) and re-organize it such that `/var` and `/srv` are on a logical volume backed by a file on the root drive.

*(why, you may ask? I'm making a packer image with customizations and preloaded data so that when the REAL servers boot, the data can be moved onto a data disk instead of the OS disk)*

I'm doing the following:

```
dd bs=16384 count=1048576 if=/dev/zero of=/.img-loop0
sync
losetup /dev/loop0 /.img-loop0
pvcreate /dev/loop0
vgcreate data /dev/loop0
lvcreate -l 100%FREE data -n var
mkfs.ext4 -L var -E nodiscard /dev/data/var
echo "/dev/data/var /var ext4 defaults 1 1" >> /etc/fstab
cd /var
mount /var
echo Moving old /var to new /var
mv * /var
echo Moving /srv to /var/srv
mv /srv /var/
ln -s var/srv /
```

and then doing an losetup in `local-bottom`

```
#!/bin/sh               
PREREQ=""               
prereqs()
{   
  echo "$PREREQ"
}             

case $1 in             
prereqs)                        
  prereqs                       
  exit 0
  ;;                            
esac                            

log_begin_msg losetup beginning 
if [ -f /root/.img-loop0 ]; then
  #mount /root -o remount,nodiscard
  losetup /dev/loop0 /root/.img-loop0
else                            
  log_warning_msg No /root/.img-loop0
fi                              
log_end_msg losetup finished
```

This all works great up until the reboot when everything goes to :

```
[   15.538463] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   15.572786] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   15.854354] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
[   15.882127] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   16.028060] random: lvm urandom read with 115 bits of entropy available
[   16.114088] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   16.403521] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   16.502056] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 1606657, lost async page write
[   16.541149] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost async page write
[   16.760508] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 0, lost sync page write
[   16.760882] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   17.722159] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 264766 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1082509)
[   17.784249] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1082509
[   19.248031] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 264774 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1094480)
[   19.248035] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1094480
[   19.829079] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262206 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1096192)
[   19.829083] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1096192
[   20.011549] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 264763 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1096193)
[   20.011553] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1096193
[   20.043613] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 264777 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1096194)
[   20.043616] Buffer I/O error on device dm-0, logical block 1096194
[   20.080044] EXT4-fs warning (device dm-0): ext4_end_bio:317: I/O error -5 writing to inode 264778 (offset 0 size 4096 starting block 1096195)
```

I don't know what's going wrong here… I think I've narrowed out any sort of thinning/discarding as being the problem.

---

While writing this up I started wondering: perhaps I'm doing this too early and the `losetup` is capturing a file that's on an overlayfs of a read-only root… that might explain these errors.

When *should* I be doing the `losetup` so `/dev/loop0` gets picked up by LVM?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the mistake I was making was setting up the loopback device during initramfs, during which time the root filesystem is still read-only. Thus, changes that the loop device attempts to write to the backing file fail.

Responsibility for remounting the root filesystem as read-write belongs to upstart/systemd/etc., so I needed to add the following to `/etc/init/lvmloop.conf` to get it to work.

```
description "custom local LVM loopback device and setup"

start on mounted MOUNTPOINT=/

task

console output

script
LOOP0=/.img-loop0

if [ -f $LOOP0 ]; then
  losetup /dev/loop0 $LOOP0  # set up loop device...
  vgscan                     # scan for new PVs
  vgchange -ay               # activate VGs
  vgmknodes -v               # makes missing device nodes in /dev
  mount /var                 # for some reason mountall fails to do this...
fi
end script
```

It would feel "nicer" if there was a spot I could put this such that I didn't need to do these steps manually, but at least IT WORKS.